# ...есть(,) с чем сравнить

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, цельное-выражение

В одних предложениях ставят запятую перед "с чем", в других – нет. Почему?

**Примеры:**

Теперь, по крайней мере, мне есть, с чем сравнить свое прошлое.

Тем более что, пусть мне поверят, мне есть с чем сравнить.

Образование там хорошее, мне есть, с чем сравнить.

Если добавить, что благодаря моим родителям я слышал двух гениев, из тех, что «смежили очи», ― Анну Андреевну и Бориса Леонидовича и однажды Николая Заболоцкого, то мне есть с чем сравнить и о чем подумать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему по-разному пишут? Видимо, потому, что не все знакомы с этим правилом:

> 7. Внутри выражений типа ***есть чем заняться, есть над чем поработать, было о чём подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать, осталось на что жить***, состоящих из глагола *быть*, или *найти (найтись)*, или *остаться* и вопросительно-относительного местоимения либо наречия (*кто, что, где, куда, когда* и т. д.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола, запятая не ставится: *Тебе есть в мире что забыть* (Л.); *Бранить есть кому, кормить — некому* (Даль); *Есть чему и нравиться* (Пис); *И нашу интеллигенцию есть за что любить, есть за что уважать* (М. Г.); *Есть над чем задуматься; Нашли чем удивить; Не нашёлся что сказать; У нас будет чем козырнуть; Нашла где модничать; Есть когда с тобой болтать!; Было отчего приуныть; Друзьям есть о чём поговорить; Ребятам было где проводить свободное время; Нам было в чём упрекнуть его*.

[**Цельные по смыслу выражения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146) (справочник Розенталя)

Во всех приведенных в вопросе примерах не следует ставить запятую после ***есть***, так как без последующих слов получится бессмыслица.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли разобраться! Кстати, все примеры взяты из Нацкорпуса. Здесь на него часто ссылаются.

Comment: @ТапочкинВениамин Спасибо и Вам за вопрос. Нацкорпус  – хорошая штука, он помогает проанализировать практику письма, дает статистику и пр., но там очень много и некачественных примеров писательства, поэтому нужно всегда критически относиться и опираться на авторитетных авторов и издательства.

Comment: Хорошо, что предупредили! :)

Answer (score 0):

Это словосочетание может рассматриваться и как неразложимое сочетание, эквивалентное члену предложения, и как придаточное.

Подробно об этом [в справочнике](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm#_=).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @ТапочкинВениамин Когда наберете 15 баллов репутации, сможете не только принимать ответ, но и благодарить любых участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы, нажимая стрелочку (треугольник) вверх.